# "warning: operation of ... may be undefined" for ternary operation -- not if/else block

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

Here's my code:

```
int main() {
    static int test = 0;
    const int anotherInt = 1;
    test = anotherInt > test ? test++ : 0;
    if (anotherInt > test)
        test++;
    else
        test = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the warning produced when I build it:

```
../main.cpp:15:40: warning: operation on ‘test’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
  test=     anotherInt>test ? test++ : 0;
                                        ^
```

Why does C++ give me a warning on the ternary operation, but not the regular `if..else` statement?

Comment: Your `if` isn't equivalent. Your ternary is doing `test = test++;`

Comment: You changed `test++` to `test=test++`, which makes a big difference.

Comment: Note that the _undefined_ refers to the output of the expression, not that of any variable.  Different compilers will evaluate "text = text++" differently; thus, it gets flagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not equivalent. Note that in the ternary operator expression, you assigned the result to `test`

Change the `if` condition to:

```
if(anotherInt > test)
    test = test++;  // undefined!
```

You would probably see the same warning here as well.

Comment: Yep, I got the same warning. If I want to use a ternary operator, what must I do?

Comment: @Username Replace `test++` with `test + 1`.

Comment: `test = anotherInt > test ? test+1 : 0;`

Answer (score -3):

u may know that in this code:       anotherInt>test ? test++ : 0; the computer maybe run test++ first,maybe run anotherInt>test ? first.so in a expression,if u use a variable ,u should not change it in some other place in this expression .U can change test++ to test+1.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The condition of the ternary operator is guaranteed to be evaluated before either expression.